# .PasswordChar property of userform textbox not working in Mac Excel

Tags: excel, vba, macos

`.PasswordChar` property masks the textbox input with whatever the symbol user chooses properly in Excel for Windows but not Excel for Mac.

I worked through `Textbox1_Change` events, but It's not working efficiently.

Can anyone hint me what should I do?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Dim mystring As Variant
    Dim textlen As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer

    mystring = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
    textlen = VBA.Len(mystring)

    If VBA.Right(mystring, 1) = "*" Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf VBA.Right(mystring, 1) <> "*" Then
    End If

    If shes = vbNullString Then
    Else
    shes = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    End If

    For counter = 1 To textlen
        If textlen > 0 Then
            If VBA.Mid(mystring, counter, 1) = "*" Then
            Else
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value & VBA.Mid(mystring, counter, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If textlen > 0 Then
        UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = VBA.Replace(mystring, VBA.Mid(mystring, textlen, 1), "*")
    End If

End Sub
```

Here is the code that worked for me in Windows and MAC excel both.

but the limitation is that the code is wont to allow the user to edit the textbox value while writing. so it's somehow getting more secure. here is the code.

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Dim mystring As Variant
    Dim textlen As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim passlen As Integer

    mystring = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
    textlen = VBA.Len(mystring)
    passlen = VBA.Len(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value)

    If VBA.Right(mystring, 1) = "*" Then
        If passlen <> textlen Then
            MsgBox "You're not allowed to do so"
            UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = ""
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = ""
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Exit Sub
    End If

    For counter = 1 To textlen
        If textlen > 0 Then
            If VBA.Mid(mystring, counter, 1) = "*" Then
            Else
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value & VBA.Mid(mystring, counter, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If textlen > 0 Then
        UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = VBA.Replace(mystring, VBA.Mid(mystring, textlen, 1), "*")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please share your code and explain how it isn't working

Comment: @ashleedawg added the code. Please see.

Answer (score 0):

This was quite tricky to solve. .PasswordChar Property of Userform Textbox isn't available for MAC Excel. So, if I want to make it Excel Applications more portable and universal then I have to code it which executed the same results.

Anyhow, I found the solution through Textbox1_Change event. The limitation of my version is only if the user wants to edit or delete any single text of the password string, then it won't allows the user to do so. I don't think it's a limitation, it may provide more strength to the password masking.

Well here is the code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Dim mystring As Variant
    Dim textlen As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim passlen As Integer

    mystring = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
    textlen = VBA.Len(mystring)
    passlen = VBA.Len(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value)

    If VBA.Right(mystring, 1) = "*" Then
        If passlen <> textlen Then
            MsgBox "You're not allowed to do so"
            UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = ""
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = ""
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Exit Sub
    End If

    For counter = 1 To textlen
        If textlen > 0 Then
            If VBA.Mid(mystring, counter, 1) = "*" Then
            Else
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value & VBA.Mid(mystring, counter, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If textlen > 0 Then
        UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = VBA.Replace(mystring, VBA.Mid(mystring, textlen, 1), "*")
    End If

End Sub
```

I'm using Cell A1 to store the actual string and will use it for login setup.